# Why does offset 0 when continuesly writing to OutputStream not result in dublicated Bytes?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

I am downloading a File via http request and reading the `InputStream` to a `byte[]` and write that `byte[]`into a `outputStream`

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
int byteRead;         
buf = new byte[conn.getContentLength()];
while ((byteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
       outStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
   }
```

Let's say my `byte[].length` is 16.
In the first while iteration the `inputStream` writes 4 Bytes `[AAAA]` into the `byte[]`.  I now have a `byte[]` of 4 Bytes with a total `byte[].length` of 16. It would look like this: `[AAAA ---- ---- ----]`. Now i write that to the outputStream. The outputStream now contains `[AAAA ---- ---- ----]`

In the second iteration the `inputStream` writes another 4 Bytes `[BBBB]` into the `byte[]`.  My `byte[]` now contains 8 Bytes: `[AAAA BBBB ---- ----]`. If I write that `byte[]` into my outputStream with an offset of 0 (the start of the `byte[]`) wouldn't that result in a doubling of the first 4 Bytes like this:  `[AAAA AAAA BBBB ----]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that there is something keeping track of the offset inside the array, there is not.

The `InputStream` / `OutputStream` often have an implicit offset (for example when they write to a file), but arrays does not.

- your first read will leave your `byte[]` with the values `[AAAA ---- ---- ----]` (assuming it reads 4 bytes).
- your second read will start from the beginning of the `byte[]` and leave it as  `[BBBB ---- ---- ----]`

This is even represented in your `write` call: the second argument tells the `OutputStream` at which index to start reading the `byte[]` and you always provide 0 (which is correct for this kind of loop).